# returns a value even when variable is assigned a null value in modal

Tags: vue.js, modal-dialog

The code is:

```
// The Vue build version to load with the `import` command
// (runtime-only or standalone) has been set in webpack.base.conf with an alias.
import Vue from "vue";
import App from "./App";

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

/* eslint-disable no-new */
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  components: { App },
  template: "<App/>"
});
```

Link to [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/5xro38y1lp)

alt_text for two product attachment is null and the third product_attachment has an alt_text value. When clicked on show modal it should retrieve the alt_text value of the product_attachment. But the value is being retrieved even for the alt_text assigned null.

Comment: Your codesandbox is throwing an error. Please update your code so that this can be reproducible.

Comment: Hi Jonathan.. Thank you for your response. Here is the updated code: https://codesandbox.io/s/5xro38y1lp

Comment: It's not working in your code because it's opening the same modal for all three products. I have made some changes in your code. Updated code : https://codesandbox.io/s/9152jr6wyp